# MySQL query for adding one or more elements to comma separated string list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have MySQL table with column name 'subscriptions'. It contains some comma separated values.

```
Id  Subscription
22  mobiles,watches,Tv,laptops
```

I need to add tablets, keyboards to this subscription field ie, my table should look like this

```
Id  Subscription
22  mobiles,watches,Tv,laptops,tablets,keyboards
```

Any special MySQL queries for this?

Comment: What is the function of the HTML here? I don't understand. If you are just using HTML for presentation in the question, don't put it in a snippet.

Comment: Storing comma-separated values in a database is most often a sign for a bad database design. As long as its just a string for you and you are not interested in its substrings, fine. But once you don't treat this as a mere thing but do string manipulations on it (which is exactly what you are doing here!) it is very likely you chose a bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this update query

```
update YourTableName set subscriptions=concat(subscriptions,',tablets,keyboards') 
where id='22'
```

Comment: Correct; it is that simple. Strange that the OP didn't find this solution themselves.